# TFX Evaluator problem with a keras multioutput model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tfx

I am using a very simple keras model in TFX, to solve a regression problem.
It seems that TFX wants that you use a keras model with named outputs, so I made:

```
output = {key: tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name = key)(x) 
          for key in _transformed_names(_LABEL_KEYS)} 

model(inputs, outputs)
```

I don't understand how the evaluator maps the label names of my dataset with the output names of my model.

In my code I set up the `label_keys and prediction_keys`  argument in `tfma.ModelSpec` with a list of form :

```
[["model output name", "Label key in my Dataset"]]
```

It seems that the proto message is created correctly, but when I run the Evaluator I get the following error:

```
ValueError: unable to prepare labels and predictions because the labels and/or predictions are dicts with unrecognized keys. If a multi-output keras model (or estimator) was used check that an output_name was provided. If an estimator was used check that common prediction keys were provided (e.g. logistic, probabilities, etc)
```

If I try to provide a single label key and a single prediction key using the `label_key` and `prediction_key` arguments I get the following error:

```
TypeError: update_state() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given [while running 'ExtractEvaluateAndWriteResults/ExtractAndEvaluate/EvaluateMetricsAndPlots/ComputeMetricsAndPlots()/ComputePerSlice/ComputeUnsampledMetrics/CombinePerSliceKey/WindowIntoDiscarding']
```

I have tried in all possible ways but nothing.
Is there a way to use a model with no named outputs (an Dense output layer with more than one node) ? Or a way to solve this problem ?

P.S. Is there a Tutorials of a TFX pipeline with a multiple outputs keras model ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

in eval_config,setting

> options=Options(include_default_metrics=BoolValue(value=False))

e.g:

```
  eval_config = tfma.EvalConfig(
      model_specs = [...],
      slicing_specs=[tfma.SlicingSpec(),...],
      metrics_specs=[...],
      options=Options(include_default_metrics=BoolValue(value=False))
      )
  evaluator = Evaluator(
      ...
      eval_config=eval_config
  )
```

Comment: Can you please expand on your answer? It is not clear how your post answers the OP's question.